# Button on bottom is sliced

Tags: html, css, button, sass

Why in bottom my button is sliced? I need that it is rounded on each corner...
Now i have this:
[image]
But if i write to orange-button class css property float: left, i get result, what i need... But it is bad idea.
[image]
How to do it in normal way?

(also i use sass+haml)

```
.orange-button{
  padding: 6px;
  @include gradient-background(bottom, $or1, #fbb752); 
  //background: url('button-carbon-bg.png') no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, $or1, #fbb752);
  @include border-radius(5px, 5px, 5px, 5px);
  //background: transparent url('button-carbon-bg.png') no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #d27d00;
  font-family: “Myriad Pro”, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: $or3;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .70);
  font-style: normal;
  @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
  border-bottom:2px solid #B16900;
}
.orange-button:hover{
  @include gradient-background(bottom, #eba641, #fcc97d); 
}
```

and fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zfq73/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to play around with the wrapper or overflows, another solution is adding `display: inline-block` to `.orange-button`.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfq73/2/

P.S. I always like to add separate css element display classes in my stylesheets called   `.inline-block` and `.block`.

```
 .inline-block {
 display: inline-block;
 }

.block {
display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="orange-button inline-block">only THIS orange button is an inline button!</button>
```

That way you can append `display: inline-block` or `display: block` to individual buttons without having to make ALL your orange buttons `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 3):

On the `.wrapper .center .right` rule remove the `overflow: hidden;`

It happens because your button is outside the elements region (overflowing, thus hidden).

**[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zfq73/3/)**